How to make API level 33 a default on flutter
I finish my flutter app and I want to upload it to Google Play Store. I got a warning that Google Play requires new apps and app updates to target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher.
I tried the steps given by Flutter  but I got bunches of errors.
Now I will try redo my app by creating a new project.
My question is how can I make Android 13 (API level 33) the default for my new and other future projects.

Can you include your flutter doctor output?

For this you can set compileSdk and tagetSdkVersion which means highest Android API level that your app supports.
you can change it in your android/app/build.gradle file.
app/build.gradle:
android {
    namespace "Your app namespace"
    compileSdk 34 //Here you can set your Compile version
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 //Minimum SDK version
        targetSdkVersion 34 //Your Target SDK version
    }
}

